# One IBAction multiple buttons and labels

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have one label, two button. One to +1 and one to -1 from the label.

I use following code:

.h

```
    int counter;

    IBOutlet UILabel *count;
}

-(IBAction)plus:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)minus:(id)sender;
```

.m

```
-(IBAction)plus {

    counter=counter + 1;

    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];

}

-(IBAction)minus {

    counter=counter - 1;

    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];

}
```

The two buttons are linked to the label(count) in IB. 
Now to my question. If I want to have more buttons and labels like this, how can I do that?
I know I can copy the code and relinked them in IB but that gonna take to long. 
And when the buttons are linked to the count label, it doesn't work to just copy them in IB, the buttons works but it counting the first label. I need to count every label each.

So, how can I do this and save time? Its gonna be many of those.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your buttons in series, store them in an NSArray, and do the same with the labels. Then you can relate them using their index in the arrays.

```
// Assuming a view controller
@interface MyVC: UIViewController {
    NSMutableArray *buttons;
    NSMutableArray *labels;
}

// in some initialization method
buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
labels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtonsAndLabels; i++) {
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    // configure the button, then
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
    [buttons addObject:btn];

    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:aFrame];
    // configure the label, then
    [self.view addSubview:lbl];
    [labels addObject:lbl];
    [lbl release];
}

- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSUInteger index = [buttons indexOfObject:sender];
    UILabel *label = [labels objectAtIndex:index];

    // use index, sender and label to do something
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. im new to this and wonder were i put this code? in the .m? i get many errors while pasting this code.

Comment: @Kallen Of course in the .m file. And don't copy-paste - this is an example, not 1:1 working code.